# Graphing a parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the video, he shows $5x^2-20x+15$ is divided by $5$ across every term and becomes $x^2-4x+3$.

Then, he proceeds to factorize the equation to $(x-3)(x-1)$ to get the roots $(1,0)$ and $(3,0)$.

Since the vertex is between the $2$ roots, we can easily know the $x$ coordinate of the vertex is $2$.

The tricky part comes, when he substitute back $2$ into $y=5(2)^2-20(2)+15=-5$ and the vertex is $(2,-5)$

I am wondering why wasn't the equation $y=2^2-4(2)+3=-1$ and the vertex could be $(2,-1)$.

[Khan Academy - Graphing a parabola using roots and vertex](https://youtu.be/MQtsRYPx3v0?t=232)

Comment: Actually it's a misue of notation, what you have writte in your last line is $y/5 = x^{2}-4x+3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to find the roots of the equation you do not need to worry about the common factor i.e. $5$. However, the $5$ does effect the scaling of the graph. Think about $y=5x$ you do not need to care for $5$ to work out $x=0$ is the crossing point, but $5$ represents the gradient of line and will be different if we plotted $y=x$.